# Use .So file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I'm developing an application for a [device](http://www.imachine-tech.com/ap02-smart-android-pos-terminal_p12.html) that has an `SDK` for itself.

When I try to import its SDK as a library in my application I will get an error like below:

```
E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-571
    Process: cards.mena.app, PID: 9484
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/cards.mena.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/cards.mena.app-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libserial_port.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
        at android_serialport_api.SerialPort.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.rt.printerlibrary.driver.serialport.ComDriver.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.rt.printerlibrary.driver.serialport.ComDriver.run(Unknown Source)
```

I put the `.Jar` file and `.so` into `libs` folder in my application like below:

[image]

And this is my `Gradle` file:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cards.mena.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10002
        versionName "1.0.2"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MenaCards-v$versionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
//            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            //    java.srcDirs = ['src']
//            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }


    }

}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"

    /*----------------/ Printer Libs \---------------------------*/
    implementation files('libs/printer_library_ap02.jar')
```

**Update:**
I downgrade my Gradle form 3.5.0 to 2.3.2 and my application is working now!

Then the problem is Gradle! What I have to do with that?

Comment: Looks like your code lacks `System.loadLibrary` call.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you explain a little more @Miha_x64

Comment: There's enough information on the internet. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Miha_x64 that not the solution

Comment: @Ehsan I am also integrating the sdk in my mobile app , but facing some alignment issue, then if you had also faced the same , then kindly let me know .. this is my skype id: vishwapratap3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and its answer.

The problem was about Gradle version and I had to add this line:

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my .so files in `src > main > jniLibs` and there in the architecture dependent subfolders `arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, ...` . Don't need additional configuration then. May be this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you don't have to as a gradle  dependency add it in the gradle app file.

```
android{

sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as @Ehsan suggested it worked.

I would like to point out something though, you don't need to downgrade your gradle.

If you'd like to put your .so files in the libs folder then you'd need to add

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
```

Its not necessary if you already added them in the jniLibs folder.

Then adding

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi'
    }
}
```

made it all work out well.